# CAAnimation runs callbacks on released CALayer -- Mac OS X

Tags: macos, caanimation

In an effort to avoid modal behavior, I allow the user to interrupt a running `CABasicAnimation`, and in the context of this application, the user's action calls for a new state in which existing `CALayers` should no longer exist.  I am not using ARC (and maybe that is my problem, but bear with this old-school question).

When the user takes action, for a group of active `CALayers` I do this:

```
for(CALayer *c in layerArray){
    [c removeAllAnimations];
    [c removeFromSuperlayer];
    [c release];
}
[layerArray removeAllObjects];
```

(Trust me that, for better or for worse, this is not an over-release of the `CALayers`).  Upon return from this routine and giving control back to the system, though, the system calls the internal OS routine run_animation_callbacks and crashes because it's trying to send messages to a zombie -- one of the `CALayers` that has been removed and released.  Why isn't `[c removeAllAnimations]` sufficient to tell the OS to stop running callbacks on that object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, leaving the answer here in case it is helpful to others.

When a `CAAnimation` is removed (with the `removeAllAnimations` call in the code above), it calls the delegate's `animationDidStop:finished:` method to tell the delegate that the animation has been interrupted.  (Interestingly, it does so even if you set the `CALayer's` delegate to nil when removing the animations).

So you can't `removeAllAnimations` and release the object at the same time.  Instead, I suppose the `animationDidStop:finished:` method will have to have some method of detecting whether it should process as normal or not.